# handle onlongclicklistener of menus

Tags: android, listview, menu, onlongclicklistener

I need to handle the selected row in listview on long click on the row but because am using menus I can't override the onclicklistener. I am trying to do this:

```
listView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        taskPosition = listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
        return true;
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "doesn't work"?

Comment: ok i got the value of listView.getSelectedItemPosition(); is equal -1 by debugger i need to handle the selection longclick on listview and use it in onContextItemSelected to perform action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i got the value of listView.getSelectedItemPosition(); is equal -1

Of course. Rows typically are not selected. Rows are only selected if the user is using a pointing device (D-pad, trackball, etc.).

> i need to handle the selection longclick on listview and use it in onContextItemSelected to perform action

No, you don't. You either use context menus *or* you use a long-click listener with a widget. You do not use both.

If you are trying to determine what row was long-clicked from `onContextItemSelected()`, [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/Inflation) that will demonstrate that for you, if your adapter is an `ArrayAdapter`. If you are using a `CursorAdapter`, [here is a different sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants) that will demonstrate this for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i think am not clarify my question , so i have example to clarify it , in android 2.2 in call log if you make long click on list of calls number and got the pop of menus you see the menus handle the number that are selected from the list of call log , thats seems what i need is how to save selection of the listview and use it in menus

Comment: @Hassan Khwieh: You find out which row was long-clicked in `onCreateContextMenu()` from the supplied `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` object. The mechanics are the same as in the examples I show, though I delay looking at this object until `onContextItemSelected()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare
How do you go about using a widget with a longClickListener. Sounds like this could be a solution to a question of mine.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844046/can-contextmenus-and-onlongclicklisteners-be-used-in-tandem